Why gRPC gave error about for protobuf library when try cross-compile for QNX?
I try cross-compile gRPC C++ for QNX. I follow below steps:

I download gRPC v1.52.2. Because I use QNX SDP 7.0 and this grpc version is the last version work with GCC 5.4.0.
Enter gRPC folder and ran git submodule update --init
Enter cmake folder and create qnx_toolchain.cmake, and create build folder
Set envirenment source ~/qnx700/qnxsdp-env.sh
Enter build folder and ran cmake ../.. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../qnx_toolchain.cmake .. command.

cmake output is:

    -- using QNX_HOST /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64
    -- using QNX_TARGET /home/arge/qnx700/target/qnx7
    -- using QNX_HOST /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64
    -- using QNX_TARGET /home/arge/qnx700/target/qnx7
    -- The C compiler identification is QCC 5.4.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is QCC 5.4.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/qcc
    -- Check for working C compiler: /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/qcc -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/qcc
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/qcc -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Looking for pthread.h
    -- Looking for pthread.h - found
    -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
    -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
    -- Found Threads: TRUE  
    CMake Warning at third_party/abseil-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:70 (message):
      A future Abseil release will default ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD to ON for CMake
      3.8 and up.  We recommend enabling this option to ensure your project still
      builds correctly.
    
    
    CMake Warning at third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/copts/AbseilConfigureCopts.cmake:70 (message):
      Value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR () is unknown and cannot be used to set
      ABSL_RANDOM_RANDEN_COPTS
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      third_party/abseil-cpp/CMake/AbseilHelpers.cmake:18 (include)
      third_party/abseil-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:81 (include)
    
    
    CMake Warning at third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/copts/AbseilConfigureCopts.cmake:92 (message):
      Unknown compiler: /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/qcc.
      Building with no default flags
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      third_party/abseil-cpp/CMake/AbseilHelpers.cmake:18 (include)
      third_party/abseil-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:81 (include)
    
    
    -- Looking for res_servicename
    -- Looking for res_servicename - not found
    -- Looking for res_servicename in resolv
    -- Looking for res_servicename in resolv - not found
    -- Looking for gethostbyname
    -- Looking for gethostbyname - not found
    -- Looking for gethostbyname in nsl
    -- Looking for gethostbyname in nsl - not found
    -- Looking for gethostbyname in socket
    -- Looking for gethostbyname in socket - found
    -- Looking for socket
    -- Looking for socket - not found
    -- Looking for socket in socket
    -- Looking for socket in socket - found
    -- Looking for clock_gettime
    -- Looking for clock_gettime - found
    .
    .
    .
    .
    -- Looking for gethostbyaddr
    -- Looking for gethostbyaddr - found
    -- Looking for gethostbyname
    -- Looking for gethostbyname - found
    -- Looking for gethostname
    -- Looking for gethostname - found
    -- Looking for getnameinfo
    -- Looking for getnameinfo - found
    -- Looking for getservbyport_r
    -- Looking for getservbyport_r - not found
    -- Looking for getservbyname_r
    -- Looking for getservbyname_r - not found
    -- Looking for gettimeofday
    -- Looking for gettimeofday - found
    -- Looking for if_indextoname
    -- Looking for if_indextoname - found
    -- Looking for inet_net_pton
    -- Looking for inet_net_pton - found
    -- Looking for inet_ntop
    -- Looking for inet_ntop - found
    -- Looking for inet_pton
    -- Looking for inet_pton - found
    -- Looking for ioctl
    -- Looking for ioctl - found
    -- Looking for ioctlsocket
    -- Looking for ioctlsocket - not found
    -- Looking for IoctlSocket
    -- Looking for IoctlSocket - not found
    -- Looking for recv
    -- Looking for recv - found
    -- Looking for recvfrom
    -- Looking for recvfrom - found
    -- Looking for send
    -- Looking for send - found
    -- Looking for setsockopt
    -- Looking for setsockopt - found
    -- Looking for socket
    -- Looking for socket - found
    -- Looking for strcasecmp
    -- Looking for strcasecmp - found
    -- Looking for strcmpi
    -- Looking for strcmpi - not found
    -- Looking for strdup
    -- Looking for strdup - found
    -- Looking for stricmp
    -- Looking for stricmp - not found
    -- Looking for strncasecmp
    -- Looking for strncasecmp - found
    -- Looking for strncmpi
    -- Looking for strncmpi - not found
    -- Looking for strnicmp
    -- Looking for strnicmp - not found
    -- Looking for writev
    -- Looking for writev - found
    -- Looking for __system_property_get
    -- Looking for __system_property_get - not found
    CMake Warning at third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeLists.txt:3 (message):
      Calling of cmake with source directory set to "cmake" subdirectory of
      Protocol Buffers project is deprecated.  Top-level directory of Protocol
      Buffers project should be used instead.
    
    
    -- 
    -- 3.21.6.0
    -- Performing Test protobuf_HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT
    -- Performing Test protobuf_HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT - Success
    -- Performing Test protobuf_HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMICS
    -- Performing Test protobuf_HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMICS - Success
    -- The ASM compiler identification is QCC
    -- Found assembler: /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/qcc
    -- Looking for stddef.h
    -- Looking for stddef.h - found
    -- Check size of off64_t
    -- Check size of off64_t - done
    -- Looking for fseeko
    -- Looking for fseeko - found
    -- Looking for unistd.h
    -- Looking for unistd.h - found
    -- Renaming
    --     /home/arge/dev/grpc/third_party/zlib/zconf.h
    -- to 'zconf.h.included' because this file is included with zlib
    -- but CMake generates it automatically in the build directory.
    -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
    -- Checking for module 'libsystemd'
    --   Found libsystemd, version 245
    -- Found systemd via pkg-config.
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/arge/dev/grpc/cmake/build
  

inside of build folder looks like below after run cmake:
    .
    ├── CMakeCache.txt
    ├── CMakeFiles
    ├── cmake_install.cmake
    ├── CPackConfig.cmake
    ├── CPackSourceConfig.cmake
    ├── gens
    ├── gRPCConfig.cmake
    ├── gRPCConfigVersion.cmake
    ├── http_archives
    ├── lib
    ├── libs
    ├── Makefile
    ├── protos
    └── third_party


I think everything is correct until here. If it is not true please correct me.

Afterwards I tried ~/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/make command. I used make command of QNX in here.I thought it was correct this way for cross compilation.

compile output is:

    arge@arge:~/dev/grpc/cmake/build$ ~/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/make
    Scanning dependencies of target zlibstatic
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/adler32.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/compress.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/crc32.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/deflate.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/gzclose.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/gzlib.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/gzread.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/gzwrite.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/inflate.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/infback.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/inftrees.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/inffast.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/trees.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/uncompr.o
    [  0%] Building C object third_party/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/zutil.o
    [  1%] Linking C static library libz.a
    [  1%] Built target zlibstatic
    Scanning dependencies of target libprotobuf
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/any_lite.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64_cxx 
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le_cxx    
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le_cxx  
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86    (default)
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64 
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64_gpp 
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le    
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le_gpp  
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le_gpp    
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_gpp    
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le  
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_cxx    
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/arena.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
        .
        .
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/arenastring.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
        .
        .    
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/arenaz_sampler.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
        .
        .   
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/extension_set.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
        .
        .    
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/generated_enum_util.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
        .
        .   
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_tctable_lite.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/implicit_weak_message.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/io_win32.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/strtod.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  1%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/map.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/parse_context.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/repeated_ptr_field.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/bytestream.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/int128.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/status.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/statusor.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/stringprintf.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/time.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/any.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/api.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  2%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/duration.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/empty.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/field_mask.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_bases.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_tctable_full.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/printer.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/map_field.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/message.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/service.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/source_context.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/struct.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/type.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  3%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/field_comparator.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/field_mask_util.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/datapiece.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/default_value_objectwriter.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/error_listener.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/field_mask_utility.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/json_escaping.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/json_objectwriter.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/json_stream_parser.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/object_writer.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/proto_writer.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectsource.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectwriter.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/utility.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .   
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/time_util.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .  
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/type_resolver_util.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
    .
    .    
    [  4%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.cc.o
    cc: targets available in /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/etc/qcc/:
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64_cxx 
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le_cxx    
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le_cxx  
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86    (default)
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64 
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64_gpp 
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le    
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le_gpp  
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le_gpp    
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_gpp    
        5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le  
        5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_cxx    
    [  4%] Linking CXX static library libprotobuf.a
    /home/arge/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntoaarch64-ar: CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/any_lite.cc.o: No such file or directory
    third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/build.make:1329: recipe for target 'third_party/protobuf/libprotobuf.a' failed
    make[2]: *** [third_party/protobuf/libprotobuf.a] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5440: recipe for target 'third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2


In the begin of compile, any_lite.cc.o file look like occur in third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/ folder. You can see in compile output. I guess any_lite.cc.o file really occur but the file can not find by the other files or paths.
I can not beyond this error. How can I fix this issue?

NOTE:
.
.

represent is :
   5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64_cxx 
   5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le_cxx    
   5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le_cxx  
   5.4.0,gcc_ntox86    (default)
   5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64 
   5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64_gpp 
   5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le    
   5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le_gpp  
   5.4.0,gcc_ntoarmv7le_gpp    
   5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_gpp    
   5.4.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le  
   5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_cxx 

compile output stucked on the body limited.

